# pytest-django: No such database error

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

I understood that the default behaviour for pytest-django is to create the test database by applying migrations and remove the database after the test run.

I have NO conftest.py file just a pytest.ini as follows:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myproject.test_settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

I run pytest with a sample test that accesses the database as follows:

```
pytest -v  test_db_access.py
```

I get an error saying:

```
E       OperationalError: ERROR:  No such database: test_database
```

If I create a conftest.py to point to my existing database, my tests all run fine.

My question is - how can I avail of pytest-django default behaviour? What do I need apart from my pytest.ini shown above?

I want pytest-django to:

- Look at settings in pytest.ini
- Create a test database
- Run migrations
- Run tests
- Drop the database

Version Info:

```
Python 2.7 
Django 1.11.12
djangorestframework
Version: 3.8.2
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's in `myproject.test_settings`?

Comment: Hi Chris I have attached the DB section from the test_settings.py  `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_database’,
        'USER': ‘test user’,
        'PASSWORD': ‘xxxxxxxxx’,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}`

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_database’,
        'USER': ‘testuser’,
        'PASSWORD': ‘xxxxxxxxx’,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}`